# Pathfinding causes stack overflow when pathing around obstacle in 1 direction

Tags: c#, path-finding

I have been working on a project which requires fairly basic pathfinding, after a fair amount of effort and time, it is nearly working.  There is, however, one bug that is persistent.  Whenever a unit needs to path above an obstacle, it has no issues, but when it needs to path below it gives a stack overflow.

The Code:

In Unit class

```
public void drawMovePath(Tile tarTile)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < moveableTiles.Count; i++) {
        moveableTiles[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.gray;
    }
    path.Clear ();

    List<GameObject> availableTiles = new List<GameObject> ();
    List<int> hValues = new List<int> ();
    calcLists (availableTiles, hValues, tarTile.gameObject);

    curTile.GetComponent<Tile> ().drawMovePathInit (tarTile.gameObject, availableTiles, hValues, path, speed);


    for (int i = 0; i < path.Count; i++) {
        path[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.green;
        print(path[i].GetComponent<Tile>().getHValue());
    }
    pathDrawn = true;
}
```

In Tile Class:

```
public void drawMovePathInit(GameObject tarTile, List<GameObject> allMoveableTiles, List<int> hValues, List<GameObject> path, int speed, int newHValue = 0)
{

    GameObject curTile = Player.instance.getSelectedUnit ().GetComponent<Unit> ().getCurTile ();
    curTile.GetComponent<Tile> ().setHValue (newHValue);
    path.Add (curTile);

    GameObject nextTile = new GameObject();

    int lowestH = 100000;
    for (int i = 0; i < curTile.GetComponent<Tile>().getSurTiles().Count; i++) {
        int index = allMoveableTiles.IndexOf(curTile.GetComponent<Tile>().getSurTiles()[i]);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            if (hValues[index] <= lowestH)
            {
                lowestH = hValues[index];
                nextTile = allMoveableTiles[index];
            }
        }
    }
    nextTile.GetComponent<Tile> ().drawMovePath (tarTile, allMoveableTiles, hValues, path, speed, curTile.GetComponent<Tile>().getHValue());

}


public void drawMovePath(GameObject tarTile, List<GameObject> allMoveableTiles, List<int> hValues, List<GameObject> path, int speedLeft, int newHValue)
{
    setHValue (newHValue + 10);
    path.Add (this.gameObject);

    if (this.gameObject == tarTile) {
        return;
    }
    if (speedLeft == 0) {
        return;
    }

    GameObject nextTile = new GameObject();

    int lowestH = 100000;
    for (int i = 0; i < surTiles.Count; i++) {
        int index = allMoveableTiles.IndexOf(surTiles[i]);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            if (hValues[index] <= lowestH)
            {
                lowestH = hValues[index];
                nextTile = allMoveableTiles[index];
            }
        }
    }
    nextTile.GetComponent<Tile> ().drawMovePath (tarTile, allMoveableTiles, hValues, path, speedLeft - 1, getHValue());

}
```

It is easiest to use pictures to demonstrate the issue:
[image]

In the image above the code is working correctly, the path is being found from the selected unit, to the tile the mouse is over.

[image]

However, in this image, the code is not working.  A path is not formed between the unit and the mouse.

The issue has something to do with the fact that once it decides a path, it always continues down that path.  The "if (speedLeft == 0)" escape clause in drawMovePath() in Tile is why only 1 tile is being displayed in the second image.  Without it, a stack overflow is created as the pathfinding loops between going up 1, then down 1, then up 1, then down 1, etc.

If I remove the = in "if (hValues[index] <= lowestH)", then I have the same problem, only in reverse, where it can pathfind below the obstacle, but not above.

I'm really at my wits end with this problem, it's been haunting me for almost a week now.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Comment: On exactly which line are you getting the stack overflow? Can you slim down your problem to a [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Most obvious here, but have you tried stepping through with a debugger? It looks like you have a pretty simple example that should be easy to track down. I don't know what algorithm you're using for pathfinding, but A* (for example, see Wikipedia article for more info) wouldn't keep following a path that is not optimal.

Comment: Also your image isn't entirely clear. I guess that the guy in the green box is supposed to be the start point and the other green boxes are supposed to be the path to where ever your mouse is pointing. Is that correct? Then what's with the green box above the guy in your second example?

Comment: @MattBurland  The stack overflow error is happening on the recursive call in drawMovePath().  As far as the images go, yes, the guy in the green box is the starting point, the other green boxes are the path.  The green box above the guy in the second example is the issue, when I prevent a path from going farther than a units speed would allow, it shows me where the path is getting stuck.  In this case, despite the path obviously needing to go right, it is going up and getting stuck.

Comment: @Frecklefoot  Yes, I have.  This is a rough attempt at A*.